# CardView rounded corner gets unexpected white colors

Tags: android, android-layout

When using rounded corner in CardView, shows a white border in rounded area which is mostly visible in dark environment. For easier understanding, check the attached image blow. [image]

here is xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4sp">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_themes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/tm_2_mip_background" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem recently.
Adding `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"` to the CardView did the trick.

Comment: You, sir, are my saviour! Your solution fixed the issue for me after a lot of wasted time!

Comment: Man you are my saviour too !!

Comment: Why isn't it yet an Accepted Answer?